# Ejecutar un script de PowerShell con multiples parametros

Tags: cmd, script, powershell

Tengo un script que necesito ejecutar en el servidor desde el cliente, lo cual hago utilizando ***Invoke-Expression*** para ejecutar un comando ***WMIC*** y crear un proceso "***cmd /c***".

En el servidor tengo el script y uno de sus parametros recibe una string que debe cumplir este formato:

`-exclude "val1, val2, val3, val4"`

Pero tengo problemas para pasarlo porque no me reconoce como valido el parametro.

Cuando construyo el comando a ejecutar, queda de esta forma:

```
WMIC /node:servername /user:remoteusername /password:remotepassword process call create CommandLine = "cmd /c powershell C:\folder\script.ps1 -Path C:\folder -Exclude val1, val2, val3, val4 -Selfdestruction" CurrentDirectory = "C:\"
```

Como los valores del parámetro *-Exclude* están separados por comas, los toma como si cada uno fuese un parámetro diferente y no se ejecuta correctamente.

Tampoco puedo pasar el parametro entre comillas, como se haria desde PowerShell porque ***Invoke-Expression***  no lo reconoce como valido.

Comment: ¿Has probado a escarpar las comillas poniendo `\"` cuando las necesites?

Comment: Si, intente pasando `-Exclude "val1, val2, val3, val4"` y tampoco lo acepta

Comment: Y con comillas simples ('val1, val2, val3, val4')?